# Composer was unable to install the updates

Tags: updates, composer

Using Craft 3 and recently installed the https://github.com/supercool/tablemaker plugin.
When I try to update Craft via the Control panel now I am getting the following error.

> Error: An error occurred
>
> Output: Loading composer repositories with package information 
>   Updating dependencies 
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.0.16.1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.16.1].
> - craftcms/cms 3.0.16.1 requires twig/twig ^2.5.0 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> Problem 2
>
> - supercool/tablemaker 2.0.1 requires craftcms/cms ^3.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.16.1].
> - supercool/tablemaker 2.0.1 requires craftcms/cms ^3.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.16.1].
> - craftcms/cms 3.0.16.1 requires twig/twig ^2.5.0 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
> - Installation request for supercool/tablemaker 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by supercool/tablemaker[2.0.1].
>
> Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.

```
{
  "name": "craftcms/craft",
  "description": "Craft CMS",
  "keywords": [
    "craft",
    "cms",
    "craftcms",
    "project"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://craftcms.com/",
  "type": "project",
  "support": {
    "email": "support@craftcms.com",
    "issues": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues",
    "forum": "https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/",
    "source": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms",
    "docs": "https://craftcms.com/docs",
    "rss": "https://craftcms.com/changelog.rss"
  },
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "3.0.15",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "v2.4.0",
    "verbb/image-resizer": "2.0.3",
    "verbb/super-table": "2.0.7",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.1.2",
    "ether/simplemap": "3.3.3",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-cpcss": "2.1.0",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-cpjs": "2.1.0",
    "mikestecker/craft-videoembedder": "1.0.9",
    "topshelfcraft/wordsmith": "3.0.2",
    "xpertbot/craft-wheelform": "1.9.0",
    "cebe/markdown": "1.1.2",
    "composer/ca-bundle": "1.1.1",
    "composer/composer": "1.6.3",
    "composer/semver": "1.4.2",
    "composer/spdx-licenses": "1.4.0",
    "craftcms/oauth2-craftid": "1.0.0.1",
    "craftcms/plugin-installer": "1.5.2",
    "craftcms/server-check": "1.1.1",
    "creocoder/yii2-nested-sets": "0.9.0",
    "danielstjules/stringy": "3.1.0",
    "davechild/textstatistics": "1.0.1",
    "doctrine/lexer": "v1.0.1",
    "egulias/email-validator": "2.1.4",
    "elvanto/litemoji": "1.4.0",
    "embed/embed": "v3.3.3",
    "enshrined/svg-sanitize": "0.8.2",
    "erusev/parsedown": "1.7.1",
    "erusev/parsedown-extra": "0.7.1",
    "ezyang/htmlpurifier": "v4.10.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.3.3",
    "guzzlehttp/promises": "v1.3.1",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "1.4.2",
    "icanboogie/inflector": "v1.4.4",
    "justinrainbow/json-schema": "5.2.7",
    "league/flysystem": "1.0.45",
    "league/oauth2-client": "2.2.1",
    "lsolesen/pel": "0.9.6",
    "masterminds/html5": "2.3.0",
    "mikehaertl/php-shellcommand": "1.2.5",
    "mofodojodino/profanity-filter": "1.3.0",
    "mundschenk-at/php-typography": "v6.1.5",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "v2.0.14",
    "pixelandtonic/imagine": "v0.7.1.3",
    "psr/http-message": "1.0.1",
    "psr/log": "1.0.2",
    "seld/cli-prompt": "1.0.3",
    "seld/jsonlint": "1.7.1",
    "seld/phar-utils": "1.0.1",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "v6.0.2",
    "symfony/console": "v3.3.6",
    "symfony/debug": "v3.3.6",
    "symfony/filesystem": "v3.3.6",
    "symfony/finder": "v3.3.6",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "v1.8.0",
    "symfony/process": "v3.3.6",
    "tcb13/substringy": "1.0.0",
    "twig/twig": "v2.4.8",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.15.1",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "2.0.8",
    "yiisoft/yii2-composer": "2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "2.0.13",
    "yiisoft/yii2-queue": "2.0.2",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "2.1.1",
    "zendframework/zend-escaper": "2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-feed": "2.8.0",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "3.2.0",
    "ether/seo": "v3.2.8",
    "pennebaker/craft-architect": "2.2.9",
    "verbb/feed-me": "3.0.0-beta.15",
    "supercool/tablemaker": "2.0.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@composer dump-autoload -o",
      "@php craft setup/welcome"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your composer.json file is specifying some explicit versions in its dependencies. Can you edit the question to share the contents of that file?

Comment: composer.json added now. Had trouble getting it formatted right on phone.

Comment: Has this been fixed already? Or does anyone know how this happens? Because I had the exact same issue.

Comment: In my case I just updated my composer.json as per the answer above and emptied the vendor folder and ran "composer update" and was then able to update craft via the control panel

Comment: Me too. Even without clearing the vendor folder. But I'm curious as to how this happens in the first place. Why was my composer.json wrong?

Comment: @TomDeSmet Are you using PHPStorm by any chance? This happened to me once when PHPStorm suggested it could "configure the project automatically based on the contents of my `composer.json` file", and I clicked "Yes". Needless to say, I'm not falling for that one a second time.

Comment: I'm using phpstorm but can't remember clicking yes to that question. I'll be keeping an eye on it for the next project I setup though.

Comment: Just had a similar problem to the one above. My error called for 'enshrined/svg-sanitize'. I removed that from the composer.json file, and then got another error calling for Twig. So I removed that from composer.json as well, ran the update again and it worked OK. Would be interested to know if anyone can explain further?

Comment: I can confirm removing `svg-sanitize` and `twig` from the composer.json file did the trick. I removed them, ran `composer update` (which installed `twig` again and `symphony/polyfill-ctype`), then i went to the admin panel, ran the update and it worked.

Comment: I've had the same issue as @Andrew and @cballenar, and their solution has worked for me, too. But the problem has returned later on, just with a different set of components. I have now cleaned up `composer.json` as @RobinSchambach as suggested in his answer, which will hopefully fix it for good. After comparing a few Craft installations, I can safely say that all those additional dependencies really don't belong there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to remove every required packages besides the plugins you installed and `craftcms/cms` as well as `vlucas/phpdotenv`, clear your vendor folder and run `composer update` again.

For whatever reasons sometimes all required packages by Craft end up in your custom `composer.json` which causes these errors

I suggest you to take a look at all your plugins and cut them from your list to another one. Remove all entries except the two above and paste the plugins again