# Can't update past 3.0.15

Tags: craft3, updates, composer

Here's what I'm getting:

```
Error: An error occurred

Output: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.0.18 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.18].
    - craftcms/cms 3.0.18 requires enshrined/svg-sanitize ~0.9.0 -> satisfiable by enshrined/svg-sanitize[0.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - craftcms/cms 3.0.18 requires enshrined/svg-sanitize ~0.9.0 -> satisfiable by enshrined/svg-sanitize[0.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - pierrestoffe/craft-language-redirector 1.0.2 requires craftcms/cms ^3.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.18].
    - Installation request for pierrestoffe/craft-language-redirector 1.0.2 -> satisfiable by pierrestoffe/craft-language-redirector[1.0.2].

Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.
```

I've attempted:

- removing `vendors` directory
- removing `composer.lock` file
- updating via CLI
- changing craftcms to `3.0.18` and running install

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue - update your composer.json file as per this question:

[Composer was unable to install the updates](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26966/composer-was-unable-to-install-the-updates)

Alot of additional things may have got added to your composer.json file.

Comment: I had this exact same problem. I just removed enshrined/svg-sanitize from the composer.json file. This then gave an error for Twig when I tried to update, so I removed that from composer.json too. The update then worked. Not sure what the implications of doing this are, if any.